# this._id undefined in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to set my `selectedDocId` upon routing to a page, but Meteor is throwing `undefined` .  I am using an `onBeforeAction` in an attempt to store the `id` that is concatenated at the end of my url via `/:id`, but I can't get them aligned.

```
 Router.route('speaker', {
            path:'/speakers/:_id',
            template: 'speaker',
            data: function(){
                return Speakers.findOne(this.params._id);
            },

            onBeforeAction: function(){
                console.log('speaker route has run');
                Session.set('selectedDocId', this._id);
                //returns undefined
                console.log(this._id);
                this.next();
            }
        });

        Template.speaker.helpers({

            editingDoc: function(){
                return Speakers.findOne({_id: Session.get('selectedDocId')});
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `this._id`, use `this.params._id` just like you did in the `data` hook.

Comment: thank you--what is the difference though?  does `this.params._id` mean that it is parsing a response, where as `this._id` simply refers to the view object?

Comment: The context (`this`) is the current route. When a route runs it parses its parameters are stores them in `this.params`. `this._id` will be available on the template (not on the route), because its context is a document.